# Loop Through Average Value in Each Row of Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, charts, datatable

I have a datatable which consists of many datarows with columns: CUSTOMER, MAX, MIN, AVG, 25TH_PERCENTILE, 50TH_PERCENTILE AND 75TH_PERCENTILE. I also have a foreach loop which will loop through each row of datatable and assign each datarow data into each series of the chart to plot the chart.

I am able to loop through average value in each row of datatable. But now I faced with other issues..

**Question:** How can I loop through the **average** value of **each point** being added to the **series of the chart**? (Please look at my code below: )

This is what I have tried (Foreach Loop):

```
                    int avg = 0;
                    int INDEX = 0;

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    avg = (int)row["AVG"];

                    Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["CUSTOMER"], new object[] { row["MIN"], row["MAX"], row["25TH_PERCENTILE"], row["75TH_PERCENTILE"], row["AVG"], row["50TH_PERCENTILE"] });

                    INDEX = Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(row["CUSTOMER"], new object[] { row["AVG"] });

                    if ((INDEX >= 1) && (INDEX <= 10))
                    {
                        Chart1.Series[1].Points[INDEX].MarkerColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                    else if ((INDEX >= 11) && (INDEX <= 30))
                    {
                        Chart1.Series[1].Points[INDEX].MarkerColor = Color.Yellow;
                    }
                    else if ((INDEX >= 31) && (INDEX <= 50))
                    {
                        Chart1.Series[1].Points[INDEX].MarkerColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
```

This is the output I get:
[image]

But the codes I used only get each index instead of average value of each index. Can someone help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the index of the added point like this:

```
            index = Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(row["Customer"], new object[] { row["Avg"] });
```

and then use it to change the marker color for each average point in your series like this:

```
                Chart1.Series[1].Points[index].MarkerColor = // some color here according to your if statement;
```

You should get something like this:
[image]

**EDIT**: This is what your `foreach` loop should look like:

```
double avg = 0;
int index = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            avg = (double)row["Avg"];

            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["Customer"], new object[] { row["Min"], row["Max"], row["Percentile25"], row["Percentile75"], row["Avg"], row["Percentile50"]});
            index = Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(row["Customer"], new object[] { row["Avg"] });

            if (avg >= 0 && avg <= 30)
            {
                Chart1.Series[1].Points[index].MarkerColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else if (avg > 30 && avg <= 40)
            {
                Chart1.Series[1].Points[index].MarkerColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (avg > 40 && avg <= 60)
            {
                Chart1.Series[1].Points[index].MarkerColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi @jstreet, thanks for your help! I tried the way you suggested but get a very weird output and I can't figure out why,,Please look at my edited post above thanks!

Comment: you just need to adjust it to your values in the chain of `IFs`.

Comment: hi @jstreet, thanks for your help! However it only get each index. it does not get the 'average value' of each index. Do you know how can I get the average value of each index then assign appropriate marker color with ifelse statement depending on the average value of each index?

Comment: Can you please post exactly what your `foreach` code looks like now?

Comment: It is still incorrect..... you're still using `INDEX` in your `IFs`.... Please look closely at my post. Btw what is `LVL1RISKCHART_POINTINDEX`????

Comment: It is NOT only that..... the main problem is that you're using `INDEX` in your chain of `IFs`.... look closely at my post.... you have to test against `avg`, not `INDEX`.

Comment: oh I know what u mean..I have changed INDEX to avg. Thanks for pointing my mistake out! Thanks for your help and guidance on this!! Appreciate it very much! :) I have solved my issue!

Comment: Glad you did it, Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can extract the row data into local variables and then perform the logic on those. I am assuming the data types, but perhaps something like this:

```
double average; 

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    average = row["AVG"];

    Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["CUSTOMER"], new object[] { row["MIN"], row["MAX"],
    row["25TH_PERCENTILE"], row["75TH_PERCENTILE"], average, row["50TH_PERCENTILE"] });

    Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(row["CUSTOMER"], new object[] { average }); 

    if(average >= 1 && average <= 5)
    {             
        Chart1.Series[1].MarkerColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    elseif(average >=6 && average <= 10)
    {
        Chart1.Series[1].MarkerColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else
    {
        Chart1.Series[1].MarkerColor=Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Ned Stoyanov, thanks for your help! :) But I encountered some issues here.. your solution is for the whole series of the chart, how can I loop through the average value of each point being added to the series of the chart?

Comment: For example: Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(row["CUSTOMER"], new object[] { row["Avg"] }); , I want to check what are the average value for each point added on the series, I want to loop through the average value for each point added on the series of the chart. Let's say there are 3 points on the series of the chart, I want to loop through the average value of each point on the series of the chart. Please take a look at my updated post, thanks!

Comment: do you mean a running average? I.e as you add point 2, it takes the average from point 1 and point2?

Comment: hi @Ned Stoyanov, I mean let's say there is few datarows in datatable, each datarow data will be used to plot one point on the chart, so one chart may have many points(the box plot), I want to get the average for each point. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Average usually means the sum of all the values divided by the number of values. how do you calculate the average for one point? I.e what values do you use?

Comment: hi @Ned Stoyanov, the average value is retrieved from database and will store it in datatable(dt).